# Problems with dividing while using for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, division

For some reason whenever I try to run this code, `speed` remains at `0` and it counts `i` up to `x` and then `speed` is suddenly changed to `1.0`. `speed` is supposed to be a decimal of `x` depending on how many times the for-loop has run through. I don't understand why this is happening and would be very grateful for some clarity.

```
 double speed;
 int x = 200;

 for(int i = 0; i <= x; i++){
     speed = i/x;
     System.out.println("Speed- " + speed);
     System.out.println("Ticks- " + i);
 }

 for(int i = x; i >= 0; i--){
     speed = i/x;
     System.out.println("Speed- " + speed);
     System.out.println("Ticks- " + i);
 }
```

Comment: Please read up on "int division".

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
double x = 200; // use a double instead of an int
```

The problem? you were dividing two `int`s, and the result is another `int`. By converting one of the two operands to a `double`, the division will now yield a number with decimals.

Answer (score 0):

x must be an float variable in order to get the correct result. If both, i and x are integers, speed is an integer too, and that's the reason you get only 0 and 1